# XDebug - which is the right xdebug.so file

Tags: php, xdebug

Configuring Xdebug with PHP Storm according to this tutorial:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-xdebug.html

I stumble across this line, that I shall add to my php.ini file
`zend_extension=<path_to_zend_debugger>`

The only thing I can find out about the zend_debugger that I shall us, is it's name: `xdebug.so`.

However,there are multiple `xdebug.so` files on my system:

`/usr/lib/php/20131226/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php/20151012/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php/20190902/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php/20160303/xdebug.so
/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so`

How do I find out which is the appropriate choice? I have no clue what the dates in the folder are to tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `phpinfo()` output, it will be at the very top: **PHP API** or **PHP Extension** rows.

Here is one for PHP 7.4.5 on my Windows 10 PC.

[image]